# Have configurations for Asp Net core 2.2 gone with Asp Net core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I have tried to create a project targeting .net core 3.0

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
```

But i could not add Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` it throws the following error after installation

```
The Microsoft.AspNetCore.All package is not supported when targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher.  
A FrameworkReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App should be used instead, and will be implicitly included by Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.  
AspNetCoreVideo C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets
```

Why is this producing this error? Does this mean we cannot use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` anymore with netcore 3.o projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ASP.Net Core doesnt use both here is the fresh csproj file for .net core 3.0 look like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Try to remove those 2 package to see you can build the project or not

Comment: it did build. So how do i import the common asp .net core common libraries with net core 3.0? is it automatically imported ( but i don't see references in the project file)

Comment: all imports should be shown on the project file right, but why this not shown?

Comment: As I said. In .Net Core 3.0 when you use "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" all the common namespace already import for you. So if you want to use anything like singlar you just reference to signalr namespace on the top of your file and you are good to go

Comment: You can check the sample here https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples/blob/master/ChatSample/ChatSample/Startup.cs